# $I_n= (-n,n)×\cdots×(-n,n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is open

Tags: general-topology

Let
$I_n = (-n,n)×\cdots×(-n,n)$ in $\mathbb{R}^k$.
($n$ is a positive integer)

Fix $x\in I_n$
Let $L=\{\min\{n-x(i),x(i)+n\} \mid i\in k\}$.
Since $L$ is finite and is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, it is well-ordered.
Let $z$ be the least element of $L$.

Let $y\in N_z(x)$. (neighborhood of x with radius z)

I'm trying to show that for every $i\in k, -n<y(i)<n$ to show that $x$ is an interior point of $I_n$, but it didn't work well.. Help

Comment: what is the meaning of $(-n,n)x\ldots x(-n,n)$?

Comment: I suspect you intend the $x$ to represent a Cartesian product? The command for that is `\times`. Also, to get the spacing in the definition of $L$ right, you should include the entire equation in a single pair of dollar signs. You can get the right font for $\min$ using `\min`, and you can escape the braces with a backslash, `\{` and `\}`. Note also that there's a preview underneath the edit window, so there's no need to post the question in a corrupted state and then fix it while everyone's reading it.

Comment: I think he means $(-n, n)^k$  Is this correct?

Comment: Right i meant that. @joriki I typed this with mobile phone since i'm now at library.. Excuse me

Comment: What is $i \in k$?

Comment: $i$ is an element of a finite ordinal $k$.

Comment: @Katlus Sorry, I still don't get it!

Comment: @Mercy natural number $1≦i≦k$ when $k$ is a natural number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have $n-x_i \geq z >0$ and $n+x_i \geq z >0$ for all $i$. Furthermore, you have $|y_i-x_i| < z$, which is equivalent to $-z < y_i-x_i < z$.

Then you have $n-y_i = n-x_i +y_i-x_i \geq z +  y_i-x_i > z -z= 0$. Similarly, you have $n+y_i = n+x_i  - (y_i-x_i) \geq z - (y_i-x_i) > z -z = 0$. Hence $y_i \in (-n,n)$ for all $i$. It follows that $y \in I_n$.

**NOTE**:

I need to elaborate on a point above. In the statement $y\in N_z(x)$, I was taking the neighborhood to be $\{y \ | \ |y_i-x_i| < z \in \forall i \}$. This is a perfectly valid neighborhood (using the infinity norm $\|\cdot\|_{\infty}$), but may not agree with your norm. A more usual norm would be the 2-norm $\|x\|_2 = \sqrt{\sum_i x_i^2}$, in which case you would need to adjust the neighborhood slightly, since the relevant bound is $\|x\|_2 \leq \sqrt{n} \|x\|_{\infty}$. If you are using the 2-norm, then you should choose $y \in N_{\frac{z}{\sqrt{n}}} (x)$, in which case it will then be true that $-z < y_i-x_i < z$.

Comment: Oh i didn't notice that $|y_i - x_i|<z$... Thank you

Comment: @Katlus: Actually, that's a good point and one I glossed over, I will add a note to the solution.